# How can df report different information depending in it's target path?

Tags: virtual-machine, disk-usage, limit, ulimit

Example:

```
root@myinstance:/my/instance/path# df -h
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/mapper/hdd-place   13T  899G   12T   8% /run/iss
...
root@myinstance:/my/instance/path# df -h .
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/mapper/hdd-place  1.0G  103M  922M  11% /my/instance/path
...
```

As you see, `/dev/mapper/hdd-place` displayed as mapped to different points and having different total and used sizes?

How can it be?

It is related with isolation or virtualization somehow.

Comment: That looks very strange. The `df .` should be looking at `/my/instance/path`. If you're inside a chroot then the apparent paths could be incorrect.

Comment: Is `df` aliased on you system? Try `$ alias df`.